# Why the symbol &#xe202; does not translate to ✰ inside the paintEvent?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qpainter, qlabel

I have this code

```
import sys
import os 
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

DIR_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

class ThinLabel(QLabel):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QPainter(self)
        qp.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        path = QPainterPath()
        path.addText(event.rect().bottomLeft(), self.font(), self.text())
        qp.setPen(QPen(self.palette().color(QPalette.Window), 2))
        qp.setBrush(self.palette().text())
        qp.drawPath(path)


class Template(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        url = os.path.join(DIR_PATH, "my-font.ttf")
        font_id = QFontDatabase.addApplicationFont(url)
        if font_id == -1:
            print('not font')
        font = QFont("my-font",18)

        super().__init__()
        grid = QGridLayout(self)
        grid.addWidget(QLabel('<div>&#xe202;</div>'), 0, 0)
        grid.addWidget(ThinLabel('<div>&#xe202;</div>'), 1, 0)
        self.setStyleSheet('''
        QLabel {
            font-size: 80pt;
            font-family: my-font;
        }''')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = Template()
    gui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And I need to make the character a little thinner
But the text does not translate into a symbol inside the paintEvent

[image]

How do I translate text into a symbol?

I have tried

connect the font inside ThinLabel(QLabel)

create another label inside ThinLabel(QLabel) but setBrush does not accept self.label.palette().text()

Comment: share my-font.ttf

Comment: @eyllanesc  The font was made on the site https://icomoon.io/ example https://dropmefiles.com/f7wcD

Comment: @eyllanesc I forgot to say code for an example. cod `&#xe92f;`

Comment: The second link you have provided is broken.

Comment: @eyllanesc Strange everything works for me. Does your page not open? or the file does not download?

Comment: @eyllanesc In any case, you can generate your own font by selecting any of the icons and clicking (generate font) in the svg file there is all the font code. They all work the same way. https://icomoon.io/app/#/select